# Basic T stat question

Tags: standard-error

I missed this on a quiz and wanted to know if somone could explain it to me so i understand it for the final! thanks. I know its probably a really simple quesitons.

With a coefficient estimate of .8, 30 observations, and a t statistic  of 4.00, whats the standard error?

Comment: Welcome to CV! We have a specific policy on self study questions. Please edit your question with the button below it and include the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the general formula for a $t$-test:

$$t = \frac{\text{difference}}{\text{standard error}}$$

And the formula for the standard error of the mean:

$$\text{standard error} = \frac{\text{standard deviation}}{\sqrt{\text{sample size}}}$$

Can you work it out from there?